# How to extract the following info from NSdictionary?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

From the Dictionary,
key=key1 value1= {email = "test1@yahoo.com";
firstname = Joe;
lastname = Doe;
sessionid = "a21ed5ba-5039-11e0-9768-7136bb0a01e4";
"user_type" = 1; }

key=key2 value2={email = "test2@yahoo.com";
firstname = Dan;
lastname = Smith;
sessionid = "a20ed5ba-7039-21e0-6868-7136bb0a01e4";
"user_type" = 2; }

in other word, the value for key1 is bunch of info , not just a simple string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the value be an array or object of user defined class.

```
@interface User : NSObject
{
NSString * email, * firstName, * lastName, * sessionId;
int userType;
}
```

you can create object of this class and insert it as a key-value pair in NSDictionary. And retrieve it back.

User * user = [dict objectForKey:key1];

Or you can insert a NSDictionary in a NSDictionary object and retrieve the values.

```
NSDictionary * dict1 = [dict objectForKey:key1];
NSString * email = [dict1 objectForKey:@"email"];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here it seems that value1 is again a NSDictionary. So value1 is a dictionary key access the values using respective keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
[dict objectForKey:key1]; will give you another NSDictionary.
```

So if you want to access e-mail from first dictionary with key as key1 you can try

```
[[dict objectForKey:key1] objectForKey:@"email"];
```